# vuejs2 beforeUpdate lifecycle hook triggers twice

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

When I unshift an array with new items, the beforeUpdate method is triggered twice. This is not the case when I push the new items. Does anyone have an idea why it's doing this? It's messing up my app...

Comment: Some code or a fiddle please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more trial and error I found the solution. I think I also can explain why the beforeUpdate method triggered twice:

- First trigger was for adding the new items to the array
- Second trigger was for reshifting the array keys because the items are added at the beginning of the array

Same problem occurred with shift. Because you remove the first item in the array, the resifting happens here as well.

This could also explain why it does not do this on a push because new keys are being added, not shifted.

And now the solution: when you do a v-for, bind the 'key' attribute with an unique value like so:

```
<div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id"></div>
```

What the documentation says about this: to give Vue a hint so that it can track each node’s identity, and thus reuse and reorder existing elements.

What I conclude from this solution is that the v-for does not look at the array keys anymore but at the unique key you provided per item.